# Видимость разделяемых переменных из разных потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Не могу разобраться с темой барьеров памяти. Когда, какие потоки и в каком порядке обновляют у себя значения разделяемых переменных?

```
bool flag = false;

void f1() {
    flag = true;
}

void f2() {
    cout << flag << endl;
}

int main() {
    thread FIRST_THREAD(f1); //Первый поток
    thread SECOND_THREAD(f2); //Второй поток

    FIRST_THREAD.join();
    SECOND_THREAD.join();
}
```

Может ли случиться так, что после того как 1ый поток, выполняя `f1()`, изменит `flag` на `true`, 2ой поток, выполняя `f2()`, прочитает старое значение `flag` и напечатает `false`?

Если да, то как нужно ставить барьеры памяти для упорядочения, что бы избежать этого? Так?:

```
void f1() {
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);
    flag = true;
}

void f2() {
    cout << flag << endl;
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
}
```

И чем это будет отличаться от:

```
void f1() {
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst);
    flag = true;
}

void f2() {
    cout << flag << endl;
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst);
}
```

Насколько я знаю, вариант `release/acquire` более производительный и менее слабый чем `seq_cst`. Что значит "менее слабый"?

UPD:

@Andrej Levkovitch, во первых, я сам не знаю есть ли проблема в моём вопросе, поэтому первое, что я спрашивал - "Может ли случиться так, что...?" что бы узнать есть ли здесь проблема или нет. Сразу замечу, что вопрос не в том, что бы  синхронизировать доступ к `flag` через мьютексы, атомарные переменные и т.д. В моём описанном гипотетическом сценарии выполнения потоков, синхронизация доступа к `flag` происходит по умолчанию: первый поток **всегда** пишет во `flag` раньше, чем второй поток читает `flag`. Вопрос в другом: может ли первый поток изменить значение `flag` на `true`, а второй поток **после этого** (то есть присутствует синхронизация) не обновить у себя значение `flag` и прочитать старое значение `false`. "у себя" имеется в виду (хотя вот здесь я уже не уверен в том, что пишу) кэш ядра процессора, на котором выполняется поток.

Comment: Во-первых, о какой синхронизации по умолчанию вы пишите - в коде ничего подобного не было. Во-вторых, с чего вы решили, что в вашем примере первый поток всегда пишет первым? Стандартом даже не гарантировано, что он начнется первым! В-третьих, какую синхронизацию вы имеете ввиду в вашем "другом" вопросе? Если синхронизация (по средствам мьютекса или атомика) имеется, то и проблем с валидным значением переменной не будет.

Comment: @ Andrej Levkovitch _"В-третьих, какую синхронизацию вы имеете ввиду в вашем "другом" вопросе?"_ я имел ввиду ситуацию, при которой, 1ый поток пишет раньше, чем читает 2ой. Например, если я запущу 1ый поток, а через час - 2ой, то они "синхронизируются по умолчанию".

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Собственно, в очередной раз попытаюсь сформулировать вопрос: запускаются два потока, **нет никаких примитивов синхронизации** (ни мьютексов, ни атомиков и т.д.). Происходит так, что **сначала** 1ый поток пишет  во `flag` `true`, **после этого** 2ой поток читает из `flag`. Может ли 2ой поток не успеть обновить у себя значение `flag` (которое 1ый поток **уже изменил** на `true`) и прочитать  старое значение `false`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B0

Comment: если вы запустите второй поток после первого - никакой синхронизацией сдесь и не пахнет... Что касается ситуации когда вы без блокировок в одном потоке пишите а во втором читаете одну и ту же переменную, то эта ситуация называется data race, и она не сулит ничего хорошего. Может быть ситуация, когда идёт последовательность запись-чтение, может быть чтение-запись, а может быть и так, что чтение происходит прямо во время записи. Последняя ситуация - это когда вы в буфер записываете строку "hello world", а при чтении получаете "hello" и какой нибудь мусор.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch _Может быть ситуация, когда идёт последовательность запись-чтение_ я про именно эту ситуацию и говорю, остальные ситуации (чтение-запись или одновременно чение и запись) не рассматриваются. Речь не о том как избежать гонки данных (элементарно при помощи мьютекса). Попробую в последний раз: **нет никаких примитивов синхронизации** Происходит так, что **сначала** 1ый поток пишет во `flag` `true`, **после этого** 2ой поток читает из `flag`. Может ли 2ой поток не успеть обновить у себя значение `flag` (которое 1ый поток уже изменил на `true`) и прочитать старое значение `false`?

Comment: на конкретно так поставленный вопрос ответить не могу, но я бы все же посоветовал бы избегать таких ситуаций, так как это (тем более при data race) вполне возможно может оказаться и undefined behaviour

Comment: Посмотрите ассемблерный код, убедитесь, что в `f1()` реально существует машинная инструкция записи в память по адресу `flag`. Тогда, если к моменту вызова `f2()` во втором потоке эта инструкция в `f1()` уже выполнилась (и вы работаете в "обычной ОС"), то `f2()` однозначно увидит новое состояние `flag`. Для надежности (чтобы однозначно "заставить компайлер" вставить инструкцию записи в память) можно написать `volatile bool flag = false;`

Comment: @PashaPash вы мне? я ставил только теги с++ и многопоточность

Comment: @zhukov хм, сорри, глюк какой-то. у меня отображались и C# и C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Несколько важных не очевидных фактов

- *Барьер памяти* (*memmory barier*, *[fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier)*) и *барьер* (*[barier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science))*) — это разные вещи. Т.к. односложного термина вроде *оградки* на русском пока нет далее под *барьером* я буду подразумевать только *барьер памяти*.
- У барьеров в C++ есть несколько назначений:

  - Сообщить компилятору, насколько свободно он может переставлять инструкции.
  - Сообщить процессору на некоторых платформах тоже самое (на x86 это не нужно).
  - Добавить в код дополнительные системно-зависимые инструкции, чтобы обеспечить когерентность памяти связанных объектов. (на x86 такие инструкции не добавляются)
- Чтобы наблюдать эффект, который оказывает барьер памяти на поведение программы или компилятора нужно **как минимум два** разделяемых объекта. С одной переменной нет **ни какой** практической разницы, используются барьеры или нет.
- Большинство операций с атомарными переменными неявно содержат барьер памяти (но это не совсем одно и тоже).
- [`std::atomic_thread_fence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) позволяет сделать эти операции немножко более оптимальными.
- Строго говоря, с точки зрения С++ `std::atomic_thread_fence` обязан работать **только** в связке с атомарными операциями. Без оных ни какие гарантии язык не даёт.

### Когда вообще нужен барьер памяти?

Допустим у нас есть две связанные переменные:

```
const char *msg = 0;
int ready = 0;
```

В одном потоке происходит присваивание (IRL можно считать, что оно атомарно):

```
void post (const char *my_msg) {
  msg = my_msg;
  ready = 1;
}
```

Во втором потоке проверяется значение:

```
void print () {
  if (ready) {
    puts (msg);
  }
}
```

На обывательском уровне кажется, что строка всегда должна выводиться т.к. в первом потоке значение `ready` присваивается сначала, а только затем присваивается значение `msg`. **НО**, во-первых, компилятор в праве переставить присваивание `msg` и `ready` местами, а, во-вторых, некоторые процессоры также сами [могут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution) переставлять эти операции местами во время выполнения; так что второй поток может оказаться в ситуации, когда `ready == 1`, а `msg == 0`.

*Барьер памяти* — это как раз та линия, через которую ни компилятор, ни процессор не будет переставлять операции. т.е. первый поток должен был бы выглядеть как:

```
void post (const char *my_msg) {
  msg = "hello world!";
  release_fence(); //< псевдокод
  ready = 1;
}
```

Во втором потоке барьер также нужен т.к. компилятор (или процессор, что вероятнее) может извратить его в нечто подобное:

```
const char *my_msg = msg;
if (ready) {
  puts (my_msg);
}
```

В итоге нужно сделать:

```
void print () {
  if (ready) {
    acquire_fence(); //< псевдокод
    puts (my_msg);
  }
}
```

### Почему `std::atomic_thread_fence` не используется на каждом шагу?

Дело в том, что с одной стороны все операции (кроме тех, что явно отмечены `memory_order_relaxed`) с атомарными переменными (`std::atomic`) неявно порождают барьер памяти, а с другой — использование `std::atomic_thread_fence` требует использования одновременно с ним атомарных переменных. Абсолютно корректный `print ()` из примера выше например выглядел бы следующим образом:

```
std::atomic<int> ready = 0;

// ...

void atomic_print () {
  if (ready.load()) {
    puts (msg);
  }
}
```

### Зачем вообще тогда нужен `std::atomic_thread_fence`?

Он позволяет дать компилятору и процессору **немного** больше свободы оптимизации. А программисту точнее описать, что он хочет. Например `atomic_print ()` из примера выше на самом деле делает следующую последовательность действий (псевдокод):

```
int local_ready = ready;
fence();
if (local_ready) {
  puts (msg);
}
```

Проблема здесь в том, что `fence()` выполняется независимо от того, нужен там доступ к `msg` или нет, а на некоторых архитекторах эта инструкция может быть достаточно дорогой. `std::atomic_thread_fence` позволяет переписать это в виде:

```
void fence_print () {
  if (ready.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
    std::atomic_thread_fence (std::memory_order_acquire);
    puts (msg);
  }
}
```

### В чём разница между барьерами [*release*/*acquire*/*seq_cst*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)?

Разница в том, какие инструкции компилятор может через них переставлять.

- `seq_cst` — самый строгий. Он гарантирует, что **ни какие** инструкции (ни сохранения, ни загрузки) не будут переставлены через него (ни вперёд, ни назад).

  ```
  load  (a)-----------+
  store (b)-------+   |
                  v   v
  --- seq_cst --- X X X X
                    ^   ^
  load  (c)---------+   |
  store (d)-------------+
  ```
- `release` — гарантирует, что все инструкции (и чтения, и записи) **после барьера** не будут переставлены раньше инструкций **записи** **перед барьером**:

  ```
  load  (a)---------+
  store (b)         |
  --- release --- X | X
                  ^ | ^
  load  (c)-------+ | |
           <--------+ |
  store (d)-----------+
  ```
- `acquire` — напротив, гарантирует, что ни одна инструкция (ни чтения, ни записи) **перед барьером** не будут поставлены после какой-либо инструкции **чтения** **после барьера**:

  ```
         <------------+ 
  load  (a)---------+ |
  store (b)-------+ | |
                  v v |
  --- acquire --- X X |
  load  (c)           |
  store (d)-----------+
  ```

#### Когда что использовать?

- Если это не критичный к скорости отрезок, то можно всегда использовать вариант по умолчанию `seq_cst`. В остальных случаях (например при создании нагруженных неблокирующих примитивов), если кратко, обычно при сохранении (в самом конце сохранения) стоит использовать `release`, а при загрузке (в самом начале) — `acquire`.
  Собственно научиться отличать, когда использовать одну семантику, а когда другую — одна из основная задач при создании неблокирующих систем.

### Односложные ответы на вопросы

> Может ли случиться так, что после того как 1ый поток, выполняя f1(), изменит flag на true, 2ой поток, выполняя f2(), прочитает старое значение flag и напечатает false?

Вообще говоря, может, но здесь это не важно т.к. эта ситуация будет неотличима от варианта, когда `f2()` выполнилась банально раньше f1().

> Насколько я знаю, вариант release/acquire более производительный и менее слабый чем seq_cst. Что значит "менее слабый"?

Он налагает меньше ограничений на компилятор/процессор.

> Вопрос в другом: может ли первый поток изменить значение flag на true, а второй поток после этого (то есть присутствует синхронизация) не обновить у себя значение flag и прочитать старое значение false. "у себя" имеется в виду (хотя вот здесь я уже не уверен в том, что пишу) кэш ядра процессора, на котором выполняется поток.

Гипотетически может, но реальной архитектуры на которой это происходило бы я на вскидку не назову. На x86 — точно не может.

---

### Интересная информация.

- [Неплохой блог](https://preshing.com/20130823/the-synchronizes-with-relation/) с несколькими статьями по теме. [eng]
- [Видеолекция](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQFzMfHIxng) по неблокирующим структурам.[eng]

Comment: _а, во-вторых, некоторые процессоры также сами могут переставлять эти операции местами во время выполнения_ процессоры (ядра процессоров, на которых параллельно выполняются разные потоки) прям в прямом смысле переставляют инструкции местами или же просто обновляют значения переменных у себя в кэшах, а остальные потоки могут прочесть переменную раньше, чем обновят у себя в кэше ёё новое значение и  с их точки зрения инструкции как-бы "переставились местами"?

Comment: @zhukov, [в прямом](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution). Инструкции исполняются квазипараллельно, когда это возможно и те что не имеют зависимости по данным, но стоят позже могут исполнится раньше. Само собой, это никогда не меняет результата однопоточной программы.

Comment: @zhukov, ранее выбранная для исполнения инструкция может начать выполняться (и завершиться) позже, чем выбранная позже нее (в том же потоке). Это называется out-of-order

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых хочу сказать, что применение глобальных переменных это (в подавляющем количестве случаев) порочная практика. А глобальные переменные разделяемые потоками - вообщем у вас должна быть веская причина для этого. Но раз уж так вышло, и вам нужно разделить некую переменную простого типа (всмысле int, bool,...) то лучше использовать atomic. Стандартная библиотека содержит атомик для bool - в данном контексте это будет лучшим решением. Если же вам нужно разделить переменную некоего класса, то тут уже нужно использовать ее в связке с мьютексом: лочите мьютекс, ассоциированный с переменной, и изменяете переменную.

Comment: извините, но это не ответ, а коментарий

Comment: @zhukov мне кажется вы в вопросе слишком уж все усложнили - описанная проблема легко решается средствами, которые я перечислил в своем ответе. Вы можете не быть согласны с ответом, но он, вообще-то, решает проблему, описанную вами в вопросе

Comment: @zhukov, если вы считаете ответом только написание готовой программы, то вы глубоко заблуждаетесь

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch обновил пост