# Многопоточный ping-pong. Использовать memory_order_acquire / memory_order_release или memory_order_relaxed?

Tags: c++, concurrency

Имеется код пинг-понга (использую MSVC 2017).
 
Вопрос: является ли он корректным? или нужно использовать memory_order_acquire и memory_order_release?

При запуске он работает нормально.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<int> cur_thread_index = 0;
const int COUNT = 10;

void func(std::string text, int thread_index)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
    {
        while(cur_thread_index.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != thread_index){}
        std::cout << text.c_str() << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        cur_thread_index.store(1 - thread_index, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(func, "ping", 0);
    std::thread t2(func, "pong", 1);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: я вижу пока только вот это `std::atomic<int> cur_thread_index = 0;` - там конструктор поправили. Надо так писать `std::atomic<int> cur_thread_index {0};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё нормально. `memory_order_relaxed` говорит компилятору не добавлять барьер памяти при выполнении данной операции, а барьеры памяти имеет смысл добавлять только при работе более чем с одним разделяемым объектом: в таком случае результаты работы программы неотличимы от работы без  барьера. Подробнее о том, что такое барьеры памяти смотри [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052530/%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2/1052779#1052779).

Надо помнить, что x86 на уровне архитектуры не поддерживает ни какие расслабленные модели памяти и на нём в любом случае практически все<sup>*</sup> операции с атомарными переменными будут выполняться точно также как и операции`memory_order_seq_cst`. т.е. единственное, на что влияет этот параметр при компиляции под x86, на сколько свободно компилятор может переставлять вычисление операций.

---

<sup>* У меня нет полной уверенности, что это применимо абсолютно ко всем, хотя скорей всего это так</sup>

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Кажется разобрался. [ссылка](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) Здесь написано, что x86 имеет Strong memory model, и все таки какие то переупорядочивания она может делать, а все операции по умолчанию acquire/release. Как я понимаю, если я такой код компилирую для x86, то вместо relaxed будет как раз ставиться acquire/release.
Интересно, если этот же код компилировать для ARM со слабой моделью памяти, то он будет уже иметь undefined behavior. Т.к cout это общий ресурс, и доступ к нему не синхронезирован, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Temp12, всё не совсем так, я уже писал, [о том, какие бывают барьеры и для чего они нужны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052530/%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2/1052779#1052779).

Comment: Независимо от архитектуры порядок доступа к памяти налагает ограничения на оптимизации компилятора, так что неправильное использование оных всё ещё может вызвать баг, но его сложнее заметить и выгоды от использования более слабых ограничений на x86 практически нет.

Comment: За `cout` вообще не беспокойся: во-первых, ты фактически сделал spin-lock, так что в один момент времени с `cout`'ом всегда работает только один поток. Во-вторых, компилятор тут, само собой, ничего переставлять не сможет т.к. вызов `operator<<` для `iostream`'а — это функция порождающая побочные эффекты, а следовательно является точкой следования через которую компилятор не вправе переставлять что-либо. И в-третьих, `cout` — это потокобезопасный объект с полноценными блокировками при доступе к данным...